# How to distinguish philosophy and literature?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-language, literary-theory, demarcation

## How can we impartially distinguish philosophy and literature?

In other words, if in the whole of an author's work there is not one single knowledge claim, then is it misnomer that the work be described as "philosophy"? If an author issues no knowledge claims, then is the work of literature philosophy? How then to distinguish philosophy from literature? Does such a demarcation render a scientific journal philosophy?

Comment: @JohnAm "...can be considered..." is a *weltanschauung*, poetry i.e. "what is to you" not "what is". Knowledge is empirical verification of what is (else how do you know what is?) not validation of *what is to you.* Such a "to you" conception of knowledge disparages knowledge for opinion and confuses observer-relativity with observer-independence

Comment: Knowledge involves reason. Reason includes categories that are not encountered in experience.

Comment: No it does not. There is knowledge you undergo ([perception](http://www.klemens.sav.sk/fiusav/doc/organon/prilohy/2012/2/9-22.pdf)) and knowledge you undertake ([verification](https://ia802605.us.archive.org/10/items/AlfredAyer/LanguageTruthAndLogic.pdf)) - neither require reasoning except as a background capability inherent with language use for making falsifiable and verifiable statements.

Comment: @JohnAm furthermore, The statements made and reasoned from require reasoning, but it is perfectly reasonable that a racoon knows if there is still food in the dumpster they ate out of last spring merely from verifying whether or not there is any food currently in it without involving any reasoning whatsoever.

Comment: @JohnAm that's quite the presumptive fallacy of ad hominem argumentation. I can't help but notice that you disregard my counter-example to your claim and do not justify your own position. Where is the love of wisdom in that?

Comment: You are trapped in a language game: you want to delineate "what philosophy is" but then bump into people who consider the  term "philosophy" to refer to things that lie outside your delineation.  But then you are stuck with a parochial definition, i.e. what philosophy is to you.

Comment: Am I correct in interpreting "knowledge claim" as: person claims to believe X, person claims to have a justification for belief in X, and person claims that X is, in fact, true.?  if not can you elaborate on what you mean by this term?

Comment: @Dave knowledge is empirical verification of what is the case. In the case of the term "philosophy" the case ("what is") stated (the knowledge claim) in the question is etymological fact. Knowledge is not a matter of belief whether true or justified.

Comment: Given the accepted answer to your meta question http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/the-rush-to-label  I'm surprised that you've formulated this question in this manner, in that it is about characterizing the nature of a person on the basis of what they've written.

Comment: @Dave, I use Nietzsche as an example of the practice of using philosophy as misnomer for author's that make no knowledge claims. You can substitute Hegel, Heidegger, Sartre, etc... This is distinct from an ad hominem fallacy as the argument is not about Nietzsche, but the use of term. Furthermore, argument to the person is just that, to the person and where warranted, valid (as a contrast, saying "Nietzsche is not a philosopher because he didn't shave" is an ad hominem fallacy)

Comment: @Dave furthermore, this is distinct from what I tried to address in the question on meta: the habit of taking a stated position and replying with, "that makes you a..." e.g. Q: I think I don't believe in deity, does this mean deity doesn't exist? A: Well, that makes you an atheist so of course you don't think deity exists #dun.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55302/discussion-between-dave-and-mr-kennedy).

Comment: The close votes are a little unfair, no? This is a legitimate metaphilosophy question on the difference between philosophy and literature.

Comment: @JohnAm Nietzsche was not a philosopher. He is best described as a poet and cultural commentator.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing to me it seems like the school example for this close reason. It is basically a rant and a spin-off from http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/3382/2953, with no other question than "am I right?". Also, [this has happened before](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/39419/2953). Well, perhaps the edits made it better, I have not read the latest version.

Comment: John Am, Mr. Kennedy, cut it out. You can squabble all you want in [chat], as long as you keep friendly. Comments are not the place for this discussion.

Comment: @Keelan again with the jejune characterizations which could not be more of a mis-read if you tried. That my reasoning is consistent and grounded does not make one a spin-off of the other nor either a "rant". Feel free to formulate a counter-argument if you are able but neither is an "am I right?" post. Seriously, for a moderator your commentary is consistently prejudiced. Will you now accuse me again of "verbal violence" when I am simply and nicely attempting to understand your prejudice and rationalizations?

Comment: To clarify: my comment about this being a rant and a spin-off is my interpretation and had no weight in the close vote. The question was closed for the reason mentioned in the close banner.

Comment: @JohnAm if think it's fair to accuse the L.P of being mathematicians who shouldn't be called philosophers, then it's just as fair for Kennedy to accuse  Nietzsche of being a poet who shouldn't be called a philosopher.

Comment: @Keelan and yet the question does not push a personal philosophy. Again, such is a rationalization of prejudicial action.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55395/discussion-on-question-by-mr-kennedy-how-to-distinguish-philosophy-and-literatu).

Comment: Q on the relationship between the first (bold) question and the second (next sentence):  Are you asking something like: is the idea that a work needs to make a knowledge claim a necessary part of the demarcation criterion for something to be philosophy?

Comment: Can you define "knowledge claim" for us? Also I like the question on science vs philosophy. That was some quality editing you did.

Comment: @Canyon philosophy - love of wisdom - requires knowledge. Are you unsure of what the word knowledge means or what the word claim means?

Comment: No, I know what both of those words mean. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the two of them _in concert_, though, if it's your contention that Nietzsche, Hegel, et al don't make any of them.

Comment: @Canyon "an object released midair falls to the ground" and "aesthetic remarks are not hypotheses" are examples of (empirically verified) knowledge claims, whereas "that which does not kill us makes us stronger" and "he who has a why to live can bear almost any how" are statements of opinion. Got the difference?

Comment: Wisdom requires knowledge, not opinion, belief or sentiment. This does not exclude opinion, belief or sentiment preceding knowledge; it excludes opinion, belief or sentiment from substituting for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

More of an extended comment than a full answer.

This is an interesting question at one level, but it loses some of its force if one disagrees with the idea that Nietzsche isn't really a philosopher. I can see how his output can be considered poetry or literature, but I disagree with the overall position.

"For example, Nietzsche's entire canon is a matter of what is true to Nietzsche - not what is true." This itself is a philosophical position - see [Nietzsche's perspectivism](http://cw.routledge.com/textbooks/alevelphilosophy/data/A2/Nietzsche/NietzschePerspectivism.pdf).

Moreover, his contributions to the study of ethics and values in "Genealogy of Morals" and "Beyond Good and Evil" are definitely philosophical, especially the idea that morals undergo a genetic evolution and have historical basis, more so than any objective nature.

His idea of the Will to Power is a continuation of Schopenhauer's Will to Live, and has a definitely philosophical pedigree.

So the argument that Nietzsche isn't a philosopher is kind of difficult to maintain, if one sticks to a pseudo-Kuhnian sociological definition of philosophy along the lines of "Philosophy is the activity of professional philosophers".

More generally, I think the pendulum swings the other way: Even authors who are considered pure literature or poetry are still considered to have contributed to philosophy. They just did so using a different medium. Think of Voltaire, Dostoyevsky, Lucretius, etc.....

---

*Update*: Logical positivist  would agree with the view that Nietzsche wasn't a philosopher, but on their account, neither were Hegel, Sartre, Heidegger, etc...given the strict definition and very narrow scope that they accorded to philosophy as "the handmaiden of science". See the [IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/analytic/):

> At the heart of logical positivism was a novel way of dismissing certain non-scientific views by declaring them not merely wrong or false, but meaningless. According to the verification theory of meaning, sometimes also called the empiricist theory of meaning, any non-tautological statement has meaning if and only if it can be empirically verified. [...], the logical positivists concluded that the bulk of traditional philosophy consisted in meaningless pseudo-problems generated by the misuse of language, and that the true role of philosophy was to establish and enforce the limits of meaningful language through linguistic analysis.

Comment: "Looses" as in "let's loose unbridled"? ;)

Comment: Given the argument for an etymological understanding when using "philosophy", is that really a "philosophical position" or merely a statement of assessing literature? As for Kuhn's worldview, I don't see that as a sound justification as he offers only perspectival value and not epistemic merit. Thanks tho - good points, well taken regarding the honorific usage.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy in my haste, I forgot a more obvious answer to your question -- see my edit

Comment: To be sure - good reference. To be clear tho, I'm not arguing the literature other than philosophy is meaningless. I disagree somewhat with the IEP tho - the core of logical positivism was a demand for the rigor of scientific inquiry in philosophy. Thanks as well for the comment about demarcation & the close votes. FWIW I have reworded the question and voted to reopen.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy you might want to check out Karl Poppers views on metaphysics (I don't know enough about them to include them in my answer). While his falsifiability criterion is similar to the L.P's  verification principle, his views on meaning were not as stark as theirs and he did think that non falsifiable statements were still meaningful. See possibly [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-9338-8_30)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm familiar with Popper. When he gets on about his "three worlds" I start to smell *weltanschauung* instead of philosophy. But even then, he's a great writer. Open Society, Poverty of Historicism, Logic of Scientific Discovery... simply delicious - like a dark and bitter Viennese chocolate bar washed down with a heady stout.